# Invalid date format when adding worklog via JIRA REST API

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, jira-rest-api, date-fns

I am attempting to insert work logs into JIRA using the REST API from my NodeJS backend. I am able to get it to work successfully from my local environment but when I deploy (to a dockerized managed service provider that I don't have a TON of control over), the entries are rejected by JIRA with the following error:

> started: `Invalid date format. Please enter the date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ".`

I have attempted no less than 15 variations on my approach here at this point and none of them will work on the deployed server.

The code I am using to format the date successfully when I run locally utilized the `date-fns` library:

```
started: format(parseISO(entryStartTime), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")
```

I have also attempted other approaches using other formatting strings, and even tried switching to MomentJS to see if I would get a different outcome (I did not).

I logged what the date string looks like in both instances - does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

**Local - working**
Time entry before format: `2021-07-14T13:00:12+00:00`
Time entry after format: `2021-07-14T07:00:12.000-0600`

**Server - NOT working**
Time entry before format: `2021-07-14T13:00:12+00:00`
Time entry after format: `2021-07-14T13:00:12.000Z`

Comment: Considering *entryStartTime* is in a format supported by ECMA-262, try not using *date-fns* and just do `new Date(entryStartTime).toISOString()`.

Comment: @RobG - that appears to give me the same output without using date-fns, however I also receive the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ultimately get it to work using the Moment format string:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

Comment: Can you show the whole request? I'm facing the same error with posting 
```{"comment":"foobar","started":"2021-08-25T13:45:00.000Z","timeSpentSeconds":900}```
which looks to be a perfectly valid date

Comment: @NitrusCS as of 2021-12-11 it looks like the error message is wrong. The API is expecting date-time to be `2021-08-25T13:45:00.000+0000`. At least when I change it to that it works. The curl example also shows that date-time format: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-worklogs/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-worklog-post

Comment: Yea, I couldn't figure out a way to make C# output that format natively, so I had to do it in stages:

```String offSetSpecifier= StartDateTime.ToString("zzzz").Replace(":", "");```
     
```StartDate = StartDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff") + offSetSpecifier;```